# Adding LibGDX to and Existing Gradle Java Project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, libgdx

I'm working on writing a PC game in Java, and I've decided to use LibGDX for several reasons, including possibly expanding to Android. Currently, I have a lot of the underlying data structures and logic written in an existing Gradle project. The project has several modules, some of which are small utilities that I wrote to aid in the development. I've been using Intellij IDEA for development. However, the documentation for LibGDX explains how to set up a new LibGDX from scratch, but it doesn't look like there's a way to add LibGDX into an existing project.

So, is there a way to add LibGDX to an existing Gradle project that I'm just missing? If not, is there a simple way to import my existing code into a new LibGDX project in Intellij, keeping each of my existing modules intact and runnable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be a lot easier to add your existing project and its dependencies to a new libGDX project, as opposed to, adding a new libGDX project to your exiting project which can be very error prone.

In a new IntelliJ libGDX project you can add your current project as a module to do this;

`File | New | Module from Existing Sources`

Then select the directory which contains your `build.gradle` file and select which libGDX modules, `i.e. core`, should have this new module as a required dependency of it.

Doing it this way you would still have the original gradle/IntelliJ project for your existing code, and a new libGDX project with that project as a dependency of it.

You can find out more information [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/importing-a-gradle-project-or-a-gradle-module.html#gradle_import_project).